# Is there something like a clicked===true conditional statment in javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

using javascript, is there a condition something like this

```
if (clicked===true && var===3) {
function executes here
}
```

if there isn't, how can you get the same effect?

Comment: Why don't write condition inside of the function? As far as I know there are no click conditional statements in js.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Check if a button or any other element has been clicked on? Or just check if the user pressed the mouse button?

Comment: check if a butto has been clicked

Comment: You have to post more code - as stated, your question is unclear. Yes, you can write `clicked===true` in Javascript, but that's probably not what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

For mouse and UI handling the Javascript model is based on **events**. In other words what you do is

```
element.onclick = function() {
    // what to do when that element is clicked
};
```

for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="thediv">Click me</div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("thediv").onclick = function() {
            alert("Awww... why did you do that?");
        };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer but I really want to see DOM level 2 events ;)

Comment: Giving a `<div>` a pet-like behaviour... never thought of this! :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to bind an eventhandler to the element. you can do this inline with an `onclick` eventhandler. Also you can't use the name `var` because it is a reserved word in javascript.

html

```
<a id="mylink" href="#" onclick="handleMyClick();">Click me</a>
```

javascript

```
var myvar=3;
handleMyClick(){
   if(myvar==3){
      alert("you clicked the link and myvar is 3");
   }
}
```